# IE11 + JS: SCRIPT1004: Предполагается наличие ';'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Что не нравится IE11?

```
var jsFunctionLinks = document.querySelectorAll('[class="js-function-copytocb"]');
for (let jsFunctionLinksElem of jsFunctionLinks) {
  var jsFunctionLinksElemID = jsFunctionLinksElem.getAttribute('id');
  jsFunctionLinksElem.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:tbCopyToClipboard("' + jsFunctionLinksElemID + '")');
}
```

Ошибка райзится во 2 строке на 30 символе, в конструкции **for (let jsFunctionLinksElem of jsFunctionLinks){}**

Comment: Может просто IE не поддерживает [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#browser_compatibility)

Comment: Упс... Понятно, спасибо. А какой тогда вариант перебора массива элементов подойдет для данного случая?

Comment: Не помню какие методы там поддерживаются, но никто не мешает поступить примерно так `Array.prototype.forEach.call(jsFunctionLinks, function(item){...})`.

Comment: Проверить поддержку можно тут: https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_statements_for_of

Comment: Или так: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#browser_compatibility (т.е. метод `forEach()` в `NodeList` напрямую тоже не поддерживается в IE).

Comment: @vsemozhebuty так его можно вызвать через prototype.call. А вообще если это не разовая функция на это есть Babel

Comment: Как выкрутиться — посмотрите https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList , там есть примеры.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg Да, это я не вами спорил, а с вариантами, приходящими в голову)

Comment: @vsemozhebuty это хорошо что в голове есть варианты - есть с кем спорить :)

Comment: Сделал так: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(jsFunctionLinks, function (jsFunctionLinksElem) {...});`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за комментарии, по вашим подсказкам сделал так:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(jsFunctionLinks, function (jsFunctionLinksElem) {
  var jsFunctionLinksElemID = jsFunctionLinksElem.getAttribute('id');
  jsFunctionLinksElem.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:tbCopyToClipboard("' + jsFunctionLinksElemID + '")');
});
```